# DateTime Format - Quirky behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.6.1

I have been formatting date/time values for decades now.  I have yet to have one date/time format pattern not work, until today.

Up until today (5/14/2018) I have had this date format applied to all dates: `M/d/yyyy`.  Today though, no matter how I try to format the date, it always ends up being `M-d-yyyy`.

Today I was making a modification (feature request) to the web-application and experienced a unique behavior that I have not seen since I have been programming (1992+).

DateTime Formats attempted:

```
var bdt = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 ).ToString( "d" , CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( "en-US" ) );
var bdt = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 ).ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" );
var bdt = DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 ).ToShortDateString();
var bdt = string.Format( "{0:M/d/yyyy}" , DateTime.Now.AddDays( -1 ) )
```

Any advise on WTH is going on here?

Comment: First one gives the desired output on my machine with de-DE culture settings. Second works when including `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Third will always use the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` and the last will work the same way as the second.

Comment: Are you setting a specific culture in your Web.config?

Comment: Just to echo @Filburt I ran all of your code examples and was returned the expected formats. This [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#notes) in the Notes state there are some external factors that can play into the default date time format such as your computer's [Regional and Language Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#control-panel-settings) and/or setting the DateTimeFormatInfo on the current thread

Comment: @Filburt the problem is that none of those formats produce `M/d/yyyy` format.  I am trying to figure out what would cause this behavior, where the code does not override any environmental (IIS, Web-App, Server, etc) settings.

Comment: The closest, similar, behavior I am experiencing is in the CSS world.  If you want a style to take precedence no matter what else declared, you append `!important` to the end of the style.  That is the closest example I can think of that would provide a reference to the type of behavior I am experiencing.

Comment: I get slashes for the first one and hyphens for the rest . *My system's short date is set to use hyphens.*

Comment: @wazz which is why I am trying to figure out what is going on with IIS.  When I do the formats during the Page Load (Code-Behind) is where the behavior is exhibited.  Once I get it to the Client-Side, JS takes over and the formats are as to be expected.